# Route packets from any network to any network

Tags: networking, centos, routing

Assuming we have the following network topology and CentOS 6.5 on each router, how can i set ALL traffic go from ANY host in ANY network to ANY host in ANY network?

[image: Network layout]

I have already enabled

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

on all routers, and now i'm stuck with routing tables. I'm already trying to do this for several days with no result.

Answer (score 0):

`Server 1` needs a default route to `Server 2`.

`Server 2` needs static routes to `Server 1` for the two networks hanging off of `Server 1`, and a default route to `Server 3`.

`Server 3` needs static routes to `Server 2` for the three networks hanging off of `Server 2` and `Server 1`, and a default route to `The Internet`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! Can i also use static routes instead of default gateway?
And do i need to set something up in iptables? I already added following rule in *filter chain:
-A FORWARD -j ACCEPT

Comment: A default route is usually a static route to a gateway.  Server 2 is the default gateway for server 1.  Server 3 is the default gateway for server 2.  I don't know what the default gateway is for server 3, but it's the other side of the interface that connects to the Internet.   If you were to put a default route on server 3 back to server 2 you'd have a routing loop.  If you don't have an adress for the Internet's default gateway, don't put a default route on server 3.